# ¿Como llenar una matriz con los datos de un vector? (java)

Tags: java, array, matrices

Tengo un vector de x numero de posiciones, aunque en este caso hagamos de ejemplo que mi vector es de 9 posiciones, por lo tanto como le hago para guardar sus datos en una matriz de 10x10, no tengo problema con que los demás indices de la matriz se guarden como `null`, de hecho ese es mi objetivo. Lo que he intentado es esto:

```
public class Reportes {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    reporteHTML();
}

static int[] myArray = {3, 2, 8, 5, 7, 9, 7, 8, 9};

static int[][] matriz = new int[10][10];

public static void reporteHTML() {//Metodo con el cual esperaba llenar la matriz con los datos del vector
    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matriz[0].length; j++) {
            matriz[i][j] = myArray[i * (matriz[0].length) + j];//Yo pensaria que en esta en esta linea esta mi error por la forma en que recorro MyArray
        }
    }

    printMatriz(matriz);
}

public static void printMatriz(int[][] mat) {//Metodo con el cual imprimiria la matriz
    for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mat[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(mat[i][j] + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}}
```

Mas sin embargo no logro llegar al resultado que quiero.

Mi código me muestra el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por cierto, no tengo permitido el uso de `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, etc.
Espero y alguien me pueda ayudar, de antemano gracias!

Comment: Al pasar un vector a una matriz se debe de hacer una transformación del indice del vector a un indice de matriz `( i --> [ i, j ])`, esto se hace teniendo en cuenta el número de columnas de la matriz (para el ejemplo 10). Primero dividimos el indice del vector por el número de columnas de la matriz, eso nos da el `i` de la matriz ahora sacamos el módulo o residuo del indice del vector entre el número de columnas, ahí obtenemos el `j` de la matriz. Ejemplo si el indice del vector es 5 entonces tenemos `i = 5 / 10 = 0` y `j = 5 % 10 = 5`, por tanto el `[i,j] es [0,5]`

Comment: Tienes un array de 9 elementos (posiciones 0 a 8) y quieres rellenar una matriz de 100 elementos. Tienes que comprobar que si el índice es mayor de 8 no lea del array, porque no existen esas posiciones.

Comment: @isaac de que forma podria emplear eso en mi codigo? o en que parte supongamos?

Comment: pues se me ocurre  en el `for`que recorre el vector, lo primero que haría sería calcular el `[i,j]`de la matriz y luego  setear los valores en la matriz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  public static void reporteHTML() {

        // variable para almacenar la posición actual del vector
        int vectorPos = 0;

        // iterar la matriz
        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
            // corrección: debe ser matriz[i] no matriz[0]
            for (int j = 0; j < matriz[i].length; j++) {

                // si todavía quedan elementos del vector
                // insertarlos en la matriz
                if(vectorPos < myArray.length)
                    matriz[i][j] = myArray[vectorPos++ /*incrementar la posición*/];
            }
        }

        printMatriz(matriz);
    }
```